# automatically fill SecurityContext from Authorization header from Spring security authorization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, authorization, claims-authentication

I have this filter to read the token from the http header and set the security context :

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
   
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");            
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = tokenService.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                log.error("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                log.error("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            boolean isTokenValid = tokenService.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails);

            if (isTokenValid) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Is there any default implementation that I can just config and use in spring boot security that reads the Authorization header and checks the token expiry date and **then fill the needed info like user and roles in SecurityContext based on the token claims?** since it seems like a very common functionality for user authorization , I thought maybe I didn't have to implement this part myself!

Comment: https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: take a look at [official spring-boot spring-secutiry sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login). idea is to use default filter, expose encoder and decoder as beans. token creation example is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login/src/main/java/example/web/TokenController.java)

Comment: also think about storing roles (or scopes/permissions) in JWT itself as it's a self-contained security token. then when using Spring's JWT support you'll only need to provide a `JwtAuthenticationConverter` with a claim name where you store roles